# How do I organize formulas to work with columns in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Hi so I'm trying to make a spreadsheet in Google Sheets that takes two numbers and subtracts them and then does it in the next row .

So example the formula in `C1` would be "`subtract(A1, B1)`" in the first row. But then in the next row I would like it to change to "`subtract(A2, B2)`" and output in `C2`.

(Without having to go in each C cell and change the formula of course)

So how do I do that and also how do I apply a formula to multiple cells of a row (C1,C2,C3,C4,C5, etc....)

Answer (score 1):

Just put `=MINUS(A1,B1)` into C1 and then copy it and paste it in the remain rows of column C and the  spreadsheet automatically adjusts the row numbers for you.

Comment: Im not too sure I understand what you mean, I have to put -B1 for that to work correct?

Comment: Actually I guess MINUS is the correct command.  I mostly program in script so I'm not that good with cell formulas...obviously.

Comment: it isnt working for me for some reason, this is the exact function that I am putting into D2 "=MINUS ( B2, MULTIPLY( 2.5, QUOTIENT(C2,15)))"              so what needs to change here is that when I insert this function into D3 I need it to instead be "=MINUS ( B3, MULTIPLY( 2.5, QUOTIENT(C3,15)))" and so on and so forth..

Comment: Try drag fill down and click auto fill

Comment: @Cooper,`Sum(A1,-B1)` will work just as well. As well as `SUM(A1-B1)`

Answer (score 0):

@Cooper's Answer above is perfect. I'm just giving a alternative here using array formulas, because it's easy.
Put this in D2

```
              =ARRAYFORMULA(MINUS ( B2:B, MULTIPLY( 2.5, QUOTIENT(C2:C,15))))
```

Comment: I played around with that but couldn't get anything work.  Thanks for the suggestion.  I'll have to sit down with the documentation and figure out how that works.  That's the thing about this environment.  There's so many ideas shared and there's always something to learn.